# How to compare files by dimension (pixel resolution) when copying in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, resolution, copy, file-compare

How to compare files by dimension (pixel resolution) when copying in Windows 7?

When copying a file into a folder
Windows compares them by size and date modified:

[image]

Is there a way add a third compare line with dimension (pixel resolution)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to write something custom to do this.
The windows shell doesn't make this comparison.

Also you could use a tool like Beyond Compare if you want to compare the contents of two directories and make sure none of the files are the same.